# RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager computeVerticalScrollOffset() not returning correct value

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with a RecyclerView and a corresponding LinearLayoutManager. I was adding some custom scrolling features to part of my app where I would translate a custom header object along with the scroll of the RecyclerView modeled after this project: https://github.com/boxme/ParallaxHeaderViewPager (which uses ListView instead of RecyclerView).

I ran into a weird issue though. It would scroll just fine for a while but then it would jump a few hundred pixels. I added log statements to see the offset computed by LinearLayoutManager.computeVerticalScrollOffset() as I scrolled as sure enough, the offset was randomly jumping from like 320 to 1200 then it would continue computing the offset appropriately from that point.

See my answer below on how I solved this!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to this thread finally found a way to resolve this accurately, posting below the code for the overriden LinearLayoutManager, sorry its kotlin though :(, also you can read about this in [more detail here](https://medium.com/@rituel521/improving-accuracy-of-computeverticalscrolloffset-for-linearlayoutmanager-38699a9d03b)

```
class LinearLayoutManagerWithAccurateOffset(context: Context?) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {

    // map of child adapter position to its height.
    private val childSizesMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            childSizesMap[getPosition(child)] = child.height
        }
    }

    override fun computeVerticalScrollOffset(state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return 0
        }
        val firstChildPosition = findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val firstChild = findViewByPosition(firstChildPosition)
        var scrolledY: Int = -firstChild.y.toInt()
        for (i in 0 until firstChildPosition) {
            scrolledY += childSizesMap[i] ?: 0
        }
        return scrolledY
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Be aware that this does not support saving state, so onConfigurationChange/recovering from process death, the state will get out of sync and the scrolling will look weird, the way to fix this is to store the `childSizesMap` in bundle by overriding `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: @urSus tagging you to the answer just in case if you're still interested after 2 years lol

Answer (score 10):

The issue ended up being the fact that I had a very large invisible item in my list followed by a bunch of smaller items. It turns out that LinearLayoutManager.computeVerticalScrollOffset() takes **average row height** into account when calculating. This caused an issue for me since that large item at the top was throwing off the average height of the rows. I ended up solving this by adding a few smaller invisible items on top instead of one large one to keep the average row height accurate.

I hope this helps anyone who faces a similar issue!

Comment: Instead of doing that, you could override `computeVerticalScrollOffset`, `extent` and `range` for a cheaper and more proper solution.

Comment: That's a great idea! I was a little wary of overriding RecyclerView and LayoutManager methods since the classes are still relatively new and might change significantly in the future. I agree my solution was on the hackier side but at least it should still work if the class changes in the future :)

Comment: Those methods are mirrors from View so very very unlikely to change.  Also,  when we change a public method, we try to make it backward compatible if possible

Comment: @yigit any examples please?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the `takes average row height into account` ? how does actually cause the values calculated to be incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that want it, here's the java version :

```
public class LinearLayoutManagerAccurateOffset extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mChildSizesMap;

    public LinearLayoutManagerAccurateOffset(Context context, int layoutType, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, layoutType, reverseLayout);
        mChildSizesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            mChildSizesMap.put(getPosition(child), child.getHeight());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state) {

        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        View firstChild = getChildAt(0);
        int firstChildPosition = getPosition(firstChild);
        int scrolledY = -(int) firstChild.getY();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstChildPosition; i++) {
            scrolledY += mChildSizesMap.get(i);
        }
        return scrolledY;
    }
}
```